# How did Paul become a Kepler 822 worker if he can't read?

Tags: underwater

In *Underwater* (2020), below transcription:

> Paul: "If you don't know where you're going, any road can get you there."
>
> Norah: Dude.
>
> Paul: What? It's not me, Norah. It's from a book.
>
> Norah: We all know **you can't read**.

How did Paul become a Kepler 822 worker if he can't read?

Comment: I haven't seen the film so going off context here I'd imagine this is a joke.